# Searching for good open source web based log viewer

Tags: asp.net, logging, nlog

My web site runs on Azure machines, using IIS8. I'm looking for a good open source web based log viewer for logs written in the DB using NLog, obviously I prefer an ASP.NET application.

I wanted to try ELMAH but it seems too basic, and I wanted to try Graylog2 and Logstash, but I can't host them on IIS.

Comment: Elmah is optimized for error logging but you can use it as a general purpose logger via signal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441062/how-to-use-elmah-to-manually-log-errors  What Elmah excels at is providing the pretty report, and an RSS, email, etc way of looking at it. Most logging frameworks don't provide a pretty viewer, I'd recommend writing a custom "report" page because the writing of a log entry is the same for everyone, the reporting is depends on what you want to know from your log (perf? troubleshooting? security events?)