# Elmah error logging, can I just log a message?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I just installed Elmah (https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) for my ASP.NET application.
Is it possible to log a message without creating an Exception first?

```
catch(Exception e)
{
    Exception ex = new Exception("ID = 1", e);
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
}
```

So is it possible to do:

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().log("Hello I am testing Elmah");
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, you can use ErrorSignal without throwing an exception.

```
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new NotSupportedException());
```

For the custom message, you can create a custom exception.

```
var customEx = new Exception("Hello I am testing Elmah", new NotSupportedException()); 
ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(customEx);
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("Your message"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but if you don't want to create an exception you can also use

```
var error = new Error
{
   Source = eventType.ToString(),
   Type = $"Trace-{eventType}",
   Message = message,
   Time = DateTime.UtcNow
};

ErrorLog.GetDefault(HttpContext.Current).Log(error);
```

as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441147/3507333).