# Override Elmah logged error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, elmah

Is there any way of overriding the error message logged by `Elmah` without duplicating it?

I have a custom exception class:

```
public class BusinessException : Exception
{
    // detailed error message used for logging / debugging
    public string InternalErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public BusinessException(string message, string internalMessage)
        :base(message)
    {
        InternalErrorMessage = internalMessage;
    }
}
```

From the code, i throw an exception like this:

```
string detailedErrorMessage = string.Format("User {0} does not have permissions to access CreateProduct resource", User.Identity.Name);
throw new BusinessException("Permission denied", detailedErrorMessage);
```

When Elmah logs the error, it only logs `Permission denied` message. However, i need to log the `InternalErrorMessage` property of the exception instead.

I've tried to create a custom `HandleErrorAttribute` to do this, but this duplicates the exceptions logged:

```
public class ErrorHandleAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true)
            return;

        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

        BusinessException businessException = exception as BusinessException;
        if (businessException != null)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(businessException.InternalErrorMessage, exception));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'll need to create your own errorlog implementation to log anything other than the standard properties. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Using the `SqlErrorLog` as an example, you only need to override the log method & put in your own logic to modify what the `Error` class contains before calling the base implementation.

Using what @Matthew has also said will stop you logging the exception twice.

All the source code is [here](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/)

Comment: It was not the solution i was hoping for, but i guess i have no other choice

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue might be here:

```
    if (businessException != null) {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(
            new Exception(businessException.InternalErrorMessage, exception));
    }
```

When you create a new exception rather than something like this:

```
    if (businessException != null) {
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(businessException));
    }
```

I have this done the code for one of my sites and can see if I can recreate your issue later today (assuming this does not work). I think this is the SO post that helped me implement: [How to get ELMAH to work with ASP.NET MVC [HandleError] attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute)

**Edit:**

Re-reading your question and the other answer I realize I was trying to solve your attempted correction and not the actual problem. Have you tried something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115891/elmah-error-logging-can-i-just-log-a-message) which is only a slight deviation from your current attempt:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true) {
        return;
    }
    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;

    BusinessException businessException = exception as BusinessException;
    if (businessException != null) {
        var customEx = new Exception(
            businessException.InternalErrorMessage, new BusinessException());
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(customEx);
        return;
    }
}
```

Check that the `InternalErrormessage` is returning what you expect, and I expect that forcing a `return` here will prevent the exception from being logged twice. Otherwise it is essentially what you had done.

Comment: Just opened my project and I did not write the custom handler. Let me know if this was not your problem and I will try and replicate on the weekend.

Comment: return would be a good idea, but the `ErrorHandleAttribute` is used also to set the result type (create a JSON error object to return to the user)

Comment: Are you getting the error you want to see now though (so duplicated but the message you want?)

Comment: No, unfortunately i am still getting the inner exception message, and the messages are duplicated