# Log an exception without throwing it when using ELMAH

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am using ELMAH for logging in  ASP.Net app.

My question is will the following line : Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Raise(ex),  when used within a catch block throw the exception to the caller or simply log it and send out an error email?

```
try 
 {
 ...
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromContext(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).Raise(ex);

   //do some special processing

}
```

Comment: Did you try it out? What did it do? See also [How to use ELMAH to manually log errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441062/how-to-use-elmah-to-manually-log-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code logs the thrown exception (ex) in ELMAH and returns successful to the caller. In other words, Raise does not throw an exception.

If your catch block re-throws ex or throw a new exception, both ex and the new exception are logged to ELMAH and a status code 500 is returned to the caller.