# Can any of the read-only properties of custom exceptions be redefined as overridable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception

VS2013 VB or C#

After an exception is raised we can see some of its properties are defined as **Public Overridable**:

```
ex.source
ex.helplink
```

But other properties are defined as strictly **Public Read Only**:

```
ex.innerexception
ex.targetsite
```

Yet others are defined as **Public Overridable Read Only**:

```
ex.data
ex.message
```

In the SO post at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441062/how-to-use-elmah-to-manually-log-errors) Simon Weaver nicely shows how to wrap an exception so a custom message can be delivered through the elmah logging system.  When I found Simon's solution I was trying to see if the standard [Microsoft User-Defined Exceptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) could be changed to allow the properties currently defined as **Public Overridable Read Only** to actually be overridden.

**So that's my question**, as a learning pursuit.  Simon's solution works great for me to get 'private notes' into the error log that don't really rise to the level of a major exception.  I just wondered if the [User Defined Exceptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) could be modified to allow directly setting/modifying a different exception property viewable in elmah instead of using a call to a method with it's subsequent creation of a wrapped exception.